# Orthogonality question

Tags: orthogonality

Been stuck on this one:

If $\vec{x}$ is orthogonal to $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ then $\vec{x}$ is orthogonal to $\vec{u}-\vec{v}$.

Any hints?

Comment: This is a one-line computation from the definition.

Comment: @user10445 What does it mean for $x$ and $y$ to be orthogonal?  What is the definition of orthogonality?

Comment: It means that $<\vec{x},\vec{u}> = 0$. Is there another definition I should use for this?

Comment: No, that's the one.  What do we know about $\langle x,u-v\rangle$?  How can we "split this up"?

Comment: Good. Now replace $u$ by $u-v$ and use properties of the inner product to continue.

Comment: Ah! I had completely forgotten the "rules" for inner products. $\langle \vec{x},\vec{u}-\vec{v}\rangle$ is simply $\langle \vec{x},\vec{u}\rangle-\langle\vec{x},\vec{v}\rangle$. Thank you! The rest is clear to me now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\vec{x}$ is orthogonal to both $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$, the equations
$$
\langle \vec{x},\vec{u}\rangle=0\qquad\langle \vec{x},\vec{v}\rangle=0\tag{1}
$$
hold. Furthermore, the general properties of inner-products give us the equation
$$
\langle\vec{x},\lambda_1\cdot\vec{u}+\lambda_2\cdot\vec{v}\rangle
=\lambda_1\cdot\langle\vec{x},\vec{u}\rangle+\lambda_2\cdot\langle\vec{x},\vec{v}\rangle\tag{2}
$$
whenever $\lambda_1,\lambda_2\in\Bbb R$. Can you use equations (1) and (2) to solve your problem?